# Instantiate child from parent

Tags: python

Is it possible to instantiate an instance of the child class from the parent without specifically passing the child's classname?

In PHP I could do something like

```
$instance = new static;
```

How can I achieve a similar result in Python?

```
class DatabaseObject:
    @classmethod
    def findByID(caller, ID):
        query='SELECT * FROM {} LIMIT 1'.format(caller.tableName)
        #dostuff
        return Instance(stuff) #return the instance of the class that called this method

class Question(DatabaseObject):
    tableName='questions'

class Answer(DatabaseObject):
    tableName='answers'

q = Question.findByID(5)
a = Answer.findByID(5)
```

So in this example what I want the findByID method to return is the instance of a Question class or an Answer class, depending on which one called it.

Or is this approach just horrible and shouldn't be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to do anything special for this in python.

```
class DatabaseObject:
    @classmethod
    def findByID(self, ID):
        # whatever
        return self()

class Question(DatabaseObject):
    tableName = 'questions'

class Answer(DatabaseObject):
    tableName = 'answers'

print Question.findByID(5) # <__main__.Question instance at 0x109b1d638>
print Answer.findByID(5) # <__main__.Answer instance at 0x109b1d638>
```

Comment: Isn't it more idiomatic to use `cls` in `@classmethod`s?

Comment: @Eric: I don't know. Is it really?

Answer (score 1):

Since the first argument supplied to a classmethod will be the class itself, you can return an instance with `cls(stuff)`:

```
class DatabaseObject:
    @classmethod
    def findByID(cls, ID):
        query='SELECT * FROM {} LIMIT 1'.format(caller.tableName)
        #dostuff
        return cls(stuff) #return the instance of the class that called this method
```

If you only have the one classmethod `findByID` then of course it would be more direct to just define `Question.__init__` and `Answer.__init__`. But if you also have other classmethods, say, `findByExam`, `findByCourse`, etc, then I think you would be using classmethods appropriately to make other avenues for instantiation.